# Facebook integration with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am creating a simple Ruby on Rails application. It allows users to login to facebook from the application and on successful login it returns to the application homepage. I followed some of the tutorials on rails casts and http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/02/09/facebook-connect-with-rails-omniauth-devise/ . But now i am getting **http 400 error**. I have installed the gems omniauth , omniauth facebook and devise. Kindly help. I m posting the views, models and controllers for the same. My application already contains integration with twitter.

***Index.html.erb (This you can say is the home page of the application)***

```
<h1>Twitter tatter</h1>    
<form action="create" method="post">
  <label for="keyword">Enter_keyword</label>
  <input id="keyword" name="tweet[search]" size="30" type="text" />

  <input type="submit" value="search" />

  <%= link_to 'Login with Facebook', '/auth/facebook/' %>

  <!-- 
  <a href="/auth/facebook" class="auth_provider">
    <%= image_tag "facebook_64.png", :size => "64x64", :alt => "Login_to_Facebook "%>Facebook
  </a> 
  </br> 
  -->    
</form>

</br></br></br></br></br>


<div id="container">
  <% if (@tweets != nil && @tweets.count>0) then %>
```

***User.rb (Model created using devise)***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  has_many :authentications # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

***Authentications model***

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Authentications-controller

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
  flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
end
```

***Routes.rb***

```
NewYearTweets::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :authentications

resources :tweetscontroller

get "tweets/index"

match 'tweets/create' => 'tweets#create'

match '/auth/:facebook/callback' => 'authentications#create
```

I am posting code related to facebook integration, not the code related to twitter integration as it is working fine. After successful sign in to facebook, i want to redirect to the homepage that is the index page

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure in your `User.rb` you'll need to include `:omniauthable` in the list of `devise` modules. Seems like you left that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the other way on how to integrate facebook in ruby on rails

1. on your gem file, add this gem -> `gem 'omniauth-facebook'` -> this is the gem for facebook authentication.
2. create a file on your config/initializer -> omniauth.rb
   -> inside of omniauth.rb put this line:

   Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :facebook, 'APPID', 'SECRET KEY', {:scope => 'publish_stream', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => '/etc/ssl/certs'}}}

   OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
   end

***step 3 & 4 will fix ssl error.***

1. create a file on your config/initilizer -> fix_ssl.rb
   -> inside of fix_ssl.rb put this line:

   require 'open-uri'
   require 'net/https'

   module Net
     class HTTP
       alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

   ```
   def use_ssl=(flag)
     #self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt')
     self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
     self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
     self.original_use_ssl = flag
   end
   ```

   end
   end
2. download the ca-bundle.crt file here http://jimneath.org/2011/10/19/ruby-ssl-certificate-verify-failed.html and put it on your lib directory
3. Create a facebook.js, in this file you put the Facebook-SDK
   -> inside facebook.js put this

   ```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : "APPID", // App ID
       channelUrl : '//localhost:3001/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication -> change this based on your Facebook APP site url.
       status     : true, // check login status
       cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML

     });

       $(function(){
           $("ID OF YOUR LOGIN BUTTON").click(function(){
           FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                   window.location = "auth/facebook";
                   return false;
               }
               }, {scope: 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
           });


       $(function() {
           $("ID OF YOUR LOGOUT BUTTON").click(function(){
               FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                   if(response.authResponse){
                       FB.logout();
                   }
               });
           });
       }); 
    };
   ```

   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
   (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

That's it....
do not forget to add  -> required on integrating facebook plugin
 -> required on integrating facebook plugin